# Platform.device.language is returning the wrong language when I change my phone language setting

Tags: android, ios, nativescript

If I start my application and my device (Android in this case) is set to Spanish, making a call to `platform.device.language` returns the ISO code for Spanish as expected. If I minimize the application, change the language of the phone to something else and then resume usage of my app, `platform.device.language` still returns Spanish even though I have changed it to something else like German.

If I close the application entirely and then re-open it, I’m able to get the correct language. I’ve used this same workflow in past versions of NS and have not run across this issue before. Is there a newer way of getting the device language that I’m unaware of?

I’m using the following versions:

Nativescript: 3.4.1
tns-core-modules: 3.4.0
tns-android: 3.4.1
tns-ios: 3.4.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution to this issue involved just accessing the native apis.

```
  let lang;  
  if (platform.isAndroid) {
    lang = java.util.Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
  }
  if (platform.isIOS) {
    lang = NSLocale.preferredLanguages.firstObject;
  } else {
    platform.device.language;
  }
```

Apparently the Nativescript approach through the platform object will only query the device language setting once after application start.